# Unable to install python modules

Tags: python, module, installation, pip

I am completely new to python, and am unable to install python modules using
pip install, and from ____ import _____.

I want to use BeautifulSoup, and I have the tar.gz file in my directory:
C:\Python27\Lib

I don't have administrator's access to my laptop, but I can get someone who has it. Would this be a problem from installing modules? I'm actually not sure if this is where it should be, or how to proceed from here. Would appreciate any help very much, because I can't even get started. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is writting:
    `pip install beautifulsoup` on the `cmd` or `powershell`

Another way:

1. Extract the file *.tar.gz
2. open the folder of the extractor on `cmd`
3. execute `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt and paste the following (for your scenario specifically)-

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install C:\Python27\Lib\beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz
```

**Note:** Replace the package name if you have a different version.